# This ad is a bit loud

Tags: discussion, advertising

It's not BLINK, but it offends my aesthetic sensibilities.

Not so much "I don't like it, take it away", but more "I think your site looks bad like this".

There's not much point having your designers agonising over every last pixel and font colour if you're going to add a big rotten, aliased eye-sore like this.

[image]

Comment: Did you do the obligatory freehand red circle? It's hard to tell with all that red there :)

Comment: What ad? can you please be more specific /s

Comment: Ugggh. 2 or 3 different fonts...

Comment: @JonClements: wow, once seen, never unseen. I think there indeed is something hand-drawn there too, if you squint!

Comment: @JonClements, LOL, that was my exact thought whilst drawing it :)

Comment: Ow, my retinas! Someone likes hot dog stand themes.

Comment: I literally clicked on this question to see the ad. Ironic, as I use an adblocker, and it's probably the first ad I've seen today. Well played!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qn977W9HjWM

Comment: Meanwhile, the shrewd marketing team of the Advanced Developers Conference uncorks the champagne. "We made it to the main site _and_ meta _and_ to high rep users who don't see ads _and_ past the ad blockers!"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads

Comment: @Lundin they don't reduce ads on the sidebar

Comment: @Pekka웃 2 or 3 different *typefaces* ;)

Comment: @paper1111 Wouldn't have mattered - we are talking of _the marketing team of the Advanced Developers Conference_ here. They are so far ahead of us that we can't even begin to comprehend it. Did you or did you not see the ad? Did you stare at it intently for a long while?

Comment: Yay desktop publishing that makes stuff look like ransom notes.

Comment: I have an uncontrollable urge to go to a Advanced Developers Conference in 2017 now....though I'm not clear why...

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Yup, that's quite the intense ad.
We generally try to keep things tidy wrt our ads - no animation, no flash, no popups - a single image basically.
We try to make the content as well be alright, but sometimes one person's "looks alright" is another's "this is too much".

We'll see if we can get some less intense ads. In the meantime, there's a menu on the top-left side of the page where you can report bad ads to AdZerk, our ad server provider. It will stop showing you the offending ad.

[image: How to disable an ad]

Comment: Thanks for answering. As I said, it doesn't offend me, it just seems 'off' with respect to the overall 'brand' of SO/SE.

Comment: Does "offensive" refer to the content, design, or both?

Comment: So which option should we choose in this case?

Comment: Other > It burns my eyes

Comment: Also the user is clearly selecting the site in English, the labels and texts ("Hot Meta Posts", "Featured on Meta") are all in that language. Why then do they get an Ad in German? Seems illogical to me.